# Designing a project using DDD

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

Currently, I am working on a project which I design as a 3-layer application (data access layer, business logic layer, UI layer). This project should read some data from CSV files (don't ask me why CSV and not some relational DB), process them and then visualize the results. 
The problem I encountered is as follows. 
Say we have a file, Airports.csv, where we have information about some airports:

- name
- city
- website

And there is another file, AirportRatings.csv, where we have such data:

- airport name
- airport rating

The Airport object should be used together with the corresponding airport rating during data processing at the business logic layer. So the question is the following - should I design the Airport entity at the data access layer with the Rating property included in it despite the fact that the general info about the airports and the ratings info are stored in different files? How would you handle this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Note that conceptual DDD questions are better to be asked at programmers.stackexchange.com.` from the description of the `domain-driven-design` tag.

Comment: What are your business invariants? When is your airport in a valid state? Ask yourself.

Comment: To handle the Query side i would never design Business Layer. There isn't any business here, just querying. Design simple POCOs/POJOs i would recommend.

Comment: It sounds like your project is a model example of CRUD-like application. DDD is not a silver bullet - you should not use it everywhere. Maybe the domain of your application is simply processing your csv files and producing reports? If you don't have any special business requirements, I would simply stick to the transaction script.

Comment: What does all this has to do with DDD, I wonder

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is subjective and specifically relative to your domain.  Which as Jay mentions in his comment, some of the more abstract, opinionated or philosophical questions might be best answered on [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).

However... If your application is all about rating airports, it might fit your design well to add the ratings into the Airport entity.  As you have already identified, I'd imagine in most cases the separation of the CSV data (maybe it's coming from 2 different sources) probably wont dictate how you hold this data in your application.

Also whilst learning DDD it's good to put your persistence (data layer) concerns to one side.  Get your domain in a good shape first.

Comment: "it might fit your design well to add the ratings into the Airport entity" Why would it be? Why would you have to load all previous ratings just to add new ones?

Comment: I was thinking of the case where a rating is singular (i.e. 1 per airport), Maybe something like London Heathrow 4.5 out of 5 stars.  I think there's only something like 43,000 airports in the world.